# How to alter SP2013 workflow task from an ASP task form?

Tags: workflow, asp.net, custom-form, 2013, tasks

I have created SPD workflow with a custom ASP form. My form opens when clicking on a task link and I can show information about the task. Now **I want to alter the task after pressing a button, but can't make it work.**

Code of my click handler:

```
Hashtable hashTable = new Hashtable();
hashTable["PercentComplete"] = 1;
SPWorkflowTask.AlterTask(this._taskListItem, hashTable, true);
```

but it seems like this approach doesn't work, I am getting the following error:

```
NotSupportedException. Specified method is not supported. 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowTask.SetWorkflowData(SPListItem task, Hashtable newValues, Boolean ignoreReadOnly) 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowTask.AlterTask(SPListItem task, Hashtable htData, Boolean fSynchronous) 
at NewServerForms.Layouts.NewServerForms.ApprovalTaskForm_Edit.btnSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

_this.taskListItem is not null (I have checked it) and was initiated as follows in the Page_Load:

```
this._listGuid = Request.Params["List"];
this._listItemId = Request.Params["ID"];
using (SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb())
{
    this._taskList = web.Lists[new Guid(this._listGuid)];
    this._taskListItem =  this._taskList.GetItemById(Convert.ToInt32(this._listItemId));
}
```

**I have two ideas, why it is hapenning:**

1. Probably I have to use another approach for SP2013 WFs.
2. As I can see in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkflowtask.altertask.aspx), this error could be if my content type is not derived from WorkflowTask Content Type.

Most likely it is really the latter, because my task content type looks as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ContentType ID="0x0108003365C4474CAE8C42BCE396314E88E51F00F35251B8B0C24C4986783D649A695D00" Name="TaskApproveNewServer" Group="MyGroup" Description="MyCT" Version="0" Overwrite="TRUE">
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef ID="{6f78c128-5660-4835-9b03-4c08d5eef709}" DisplayName="AbsenceStatement_Status" Required="false" Description="" Hidden="false" Name="AbsenceStatement_Status" Sealed="false" />
      <FieldRef ID="{55B29417-1042-47F0-9DFF-CE8156667F96}" DisplayName="$Resources:_FeatureId57311b7a-9afd-4ff0-866e-9393ad6647b1,TaskOutcomeField_DisplayName;" Name="TaskOutcome" Sealed="FALSE" />
    </FieldRefs>
    <XmlDocuments>
      <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms/url">
        <FormsUrl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms/url">
          <Display>_layouts/15/NewServerForms/ApprovalTaskForm_Edit.aspx</Display>
          <Edit>_layouts/15/NewServerForms/ApprovalTaskForm_Edit.aspx</Edit>
        </FormsUrl>
      </XmlDocument>
    </XmlDocuments>
  </ContentType>
</Elements>
```

Its ID derived from WorkflowTask, but there is no Inherits="TRUE" attribute (it was removed, because I can't use custom forms when it is true because of the [well-known issue](http://spboom.com/sharepoint-development/sharepoint-2010-content-type-inheritance-problems/)).

**So, could you suggest me, how can I alter the task using my custom ASP form?**

Every suggestions are very appreciated.

Kind regards, Michael

PS: This is a cross-post from [Microsoft forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/bcdd1f70-6feb-4102-bb59-58df110a13c1).

**Update 1:**

It seems like the cause of the issue the former. At least, now I added Inherits="TRUE" attribute (and set forms from the Feature receiver), but anyway I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the SPWorkflowTask.AlterTask method really doesn't work for 2013 workflows, but we can change task fields directly and it works well.

For instance, instead of

```
Hashtable hashTable = new Hashtable();
hashTable["PercentComplete"] = 1;
SPWorkflowTask.AlterTask(this._taskListItem, hashTable, true);
```

We could write

```
this._taskListItem["PercentComplete"] = 1;
this._taskListItem.Update();
```

Don't forget to add Update.

**UPDATE1:** I have just written a [walkthrough: how to implement custom task forms for SP2013 WFs](http://sp2013-blog.com/?p=124).

Comment: Seems like your question is helpful but not the answer